# Rails 3: assets pipeline + many layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a huge project with rails 3.1 (without assets pipeline). This project has a lot of different layouts, for example:

- application
- home
- console

And etc. Each layout has a huge list of js and css (to attach them we use `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag`). Is it possible to enable assets pipeline so it will include different js/css files for different layouts and it will generate different application.js and application.css for each layout in production?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes it is

application.css

```
*= require this_file
*= require that_file
```

home.css

```
*= require this_file
*= require home_file
```

etc etc

you can then do this in your application layout:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

and the home layout

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "home", media: "all" %>
```

you will also need to tweak *production.rb*

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css home.css home.js )
```

including all the compiled files you reference in the layouts.